# iOS how to generate a textured mesh from a transparent .png?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a transparent png and I want to create a mesh from it. The mesh should be shaped like the non-transparent pixels in the .png with definable thickness (extrusion). This sounds like finding a convex hull and triangulating to generate a mesh but seems quite complex. I played around with SpriteKit but I've only managed to get an SKPhysicsBody:

```
func getMesh(image:CGImage) -> MDLMesh {

    var mesh: MDLMesh = MDLMesh()

    var texture : SKTexture = SKTexture.init(image)
    var physicsBody :SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(texture: texture, size: texture.size() )

    return mesh
}
```

How would I go from that physicsbody to create a mesh? Are there any swift/iOS libraries that can do this for me automatically?